# Why am I getting a route undefined error when testing my controller?

Tags: php, api, unit-testing, phpunit

I am trying to internally test an API by calling my controller actions in my unit tests. For some reason I am getting InvalidArgumentException: Route [ListController@create] not defined. Can anyone help?

ListControllerTest.php

```
use Guzzle\Tests\GuzzleTestCase,
Guzzle\Plugin\Mock\MockPlugin,
Guzzle\Http\Message\Response,
Guzzle\Http\Client,
Guzzle\Service\Client as ServiceClient,
Guzzle\Http\EntityBody;

class ListTest extends TestCase {
    public function testCreateList()
    {
        $user_id = getTestReceiverUserId();
        $response = $this->action(
            'POST', 
            'ListController@create',
            [
                'body' => array(
                    "name" => "open,shared",
                    "users" => array(array("user_id" => $user_id)),
                    "visibility" => "2",
                    "joinability" => "2",
                    "adminship" => "1",
                    "color" => "#2bc069"
                ),
                'headers' => array('Auth' => getTestAuthSender())
            ]
        );
    }
```

routes.php

```
Route::group(array('namespace' => 'App\Controllers\v2', 'prefix' => '2.0'), function()
{
    Route::controller('user', 'UserController');
    Route::controller('invite', 'InviteController');
    Route::controller('list', 'ListController');

    Route::post('/login','AuthController@login');
    Route::any('/logout','AuthController@logout');
});
```

ListController.php

```
namespace App\Controllers\v1;
use BaseController;
use Timothylhuillier\LaravelMixpanel\Facades\LaravelMixpanel;
class ListController extends BaseController
{
    public function postCreate()
    {
       Some Code
    }
```

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: I am using version 4.2

Comment: @RossWilson Do you have any idea what the problem is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would imagine that it's because you have have your `ListController` inside your `v2` namespace.

Try changing:

```
'ListController@create',
```

to:

```
'v2\ListController@postCreate',
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the quick response but unfortunately I am getting the same error. I even tried to prepend the namespace such that my route looks like this in the test... 'App\Controllers\v2\ListController@create'. :(

Comment: @JacobShafi I've updated my answer. See if that does it.

Comment: Yes! That works perfectly! Thank you very much! I ran 'php artisan routes' to see the full routes and the one you suggested was one of them. Thanks again!